# Calculating Haversine distance of two coordinates taking into consideration the altitude

Tags: java, coordinates, haversine

Today in class wev'e been introduced to the haversine function. the describtion of the function goes like this : **"This uses the ‘haversine’ formula to calculate the great-circle distance between two points – that is, the shortest distance over the earth’s surface – giving an ‘as-the-crow-flies’ distance between the points (ignoring any hills they fly over, of course!)."**

The goal is to load a csv file that inclued **lat,lon and alt** of a point and calculate the distance of 2 coordinates on earth.

My question is: how do I integrate the haversine function with the altitude factor?

Comment: Probably you need to calculate arc length in an altitude h above earth surface. Its trivial: [`d = (r+h) * Δσ`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance#Formulas)

Comment: The haversine function must have a radius, or altitude, constant somewhere. Otherwise it cannot give you distances, it would give you arcs or degrees of a sphere.